# Table design for SQL

Tags: c#, sql, database-design

i hope you can help me out here - i have a question about designing a SQL table. I know how to write to a database and perform queries using C#, but i have never really had to design one. So i thought i would give it a shot just our of interest.

Lets assume i have a table named family_surname. Within that table, there could be x amount of family_members, say ranging from 2 people to 22 people. How can i reference family_members against family_surname?

So i would have
FAMILY SURNAME
Smith,
Jones,
Brown,
Taylor,
etc.

And then Smith may have 5 members, to where i would like to record age, height, weight, whatever. Jones may have 8 members - it could vary between families.

I dont really want 'surname' listed 8 times for each member - ideally the surname row would reference (or somehow point to) a corresponding row in another table. And thats where im having trouble!

I hope i make sense; like i say, im just interested, but i would like to know how to do this with two tables.

Anyway, thank you for your help, i appreciate it.

EDIT
Thank you to everone who commented - certainly some useful information here, which i appreciate. Im reading up and researching some SQL bits and peices, and so far its pretty good.
Thanks again, guys!

Comment: You should probably read up on database normalization: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Comment: What will happen if one of your family member wants to change surname? Like due to divorce? If an entity owns an attribute exclusively I would not normalize it and put into separate table.

Comment: @val that's a valid point but it may be outside the scope of the question; OP is asking simply how to represent a list of given name/surname pairs without duplicating the surname.  Whether that's appropriate would depend on the application.

Comment: @gcbenison - true, may be it was just a bad example. [Link] to start reading on normalization.

Answer (score 3):

What you are asking is a question about normalization.  The table would look like:

```
Create table surname (
    SurnameID int,
    Surname varchar(255)
)
```

The other tables would reference the surname by  using the I'd.  Also, you probably want surnameid to be unique, a primary key, and auto incrementing.  Those are more advanced topics.

That said, I'm not sure surname is a great candidate for splitting out like this.  One reason to normalize data is to maintain relational integrity.  In this case, it means that when you change "Smith" to "Jones", all the Smiths change at once.  I don't think this is a concern in your case.

Answer (score 2):

Yes the previous answer about learning about database normalization is probably accurate but for starters....

Breaking down the person's name (first and last) is probably a bit much. Unless you are assuming everyone named "jones" are ALL related.  Think of each table as an entity/object and try to connect them to real world "objects" as much as possible.  Since a person needs both first and last name (minimum) to uniquely identify them, they should not be normalized in that way.

In the scenario you've painted, you should have a Persons table that has PersonId, FirstName, LastName.  And if need be, a separate table to store other information.  However, since the person can only be of one height, weight, age, etc... those should be stored in the Persons table.

Therefore, you really only need one table here.  Unless you start getting into phone numbers, addresses, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The decomposition can be done as follows

1. CREATE TABLE SURNAMES(INT ID, SURNAME VARCHAR2(200))
2. CREATE TABLE DETAILS(INT ID, FOREIGN KEY(SURNAME_ID) REFERENCES SURNAMES(ID), PARAM1,     PARAM2 .....)

A rough sketch of the decomposition is

Get the list of attributes (SURNAME, PARAM1, PARAM2,....). 
Based on the list of attributes the following keys can be inferred : 
1. (SURNAME)
2.(PARAM1,PARAM2...)
A separate table is created for each set of keys

Answer (score 0):

> I dont really want 'surname' listed 8 times for each member

Why? Have you **measured** on realistic amounts of data and determined it's actually a problem?

**Unless** you plan having additional data specific to the surname (and independent of persons who have that surname), there is nothing wrong about surname **not** being in its own table. You are not breaking any normal form.

In fact, what you propose can be a really bad idea, for following reasons:

- First and foremost, you'd need a JOIN just to find out person's surname - bad for performance.
- It complicates (and slows-down) insertion/modification/deletion of persons.

  - When inserting a new person, you'd have to search the surname table to decide whether you can "reuse" the existing one or insert the new one.
  - Modification (e.g. when a wife takes husband's surname) is a combination of deletion (see below) and insertion.
  - Can a surname exist without any person having it? If no, there is no good declarative integrity to enforce this. At best you'd need to write some triggers.
- You might not end-up saving much space after all - the additional table will have its own storage overheads (such as the index "underneath" the primary key) which may "eat" much of the anticipated storage saving.